# What are some books written on Indian philosophy of spirituality by western philosophers?

Tags: philosophy, book-recommendation, spirituality

It is true that spiritualism is best depicted in Hindu scriptures, and we do have some records of western saints going to Indian land for the development of their spiritual lives.

We have some western philosophers who wrote the English translation of many spiritual Hindu scriptures, for example Max Müller translated **The Upanishads** and the Indian saint Vivekananda preached in Chicago about Indian philosophy (although he was from India but what I mean is he preached in English and in a manner which was easily understandable by western culture).

But is there any epic or literary work whose main aim is Hindu spiritualism, for example Marcus Aurelius wrote **Meditation** as a complete separate book on the philosophy of meditation (that is a complete book on one topic, although the subject is not Hindu spiritualism) So, I need a book which teaches the Indian way of becoming spiritual, a book which can serve as a teacher.

Comment: @Brahadeesh I was reading about Indian Saints and found Vivekananda who actaully went to west. And I never said that Aurelius’s book is on Hindu spiritualism, I gave it as an example of what type of book I was looking for.

Comment: Do you really mean "philosophy of spirituality" in the title? Not "philosophy or spirituality"?

Comment: @Brahadeesh To be honest, I don’t know how to differentiate between philosophy and spiritual teachings.

Comment: There are many and would depend upon which philosophy is being expounded. Your question is opinion based and too general. It would be ok if you narowed it down to which philosophical tradition you are interested in, For a general overview of different Indian philosophies, try here - https://archive.org/details/IndianPhilosophyACriticalSurvey

Comment: @SwamiVishwananda I, to tell the truth, want to begin my spiritual path.

Answer (score 2):

You might be interested in perusing Aleister Crowley's magnum opus [*Magick, Liber ABA, Book 4*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magick_(Book_4)).

Crowley was a colourful character, as a quick glance at his [Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magick_(Book_4)#Part_I:_Mysticism) will tell you.  Part I of *Book 4* contains a distillation of Crowley's understanding of yoga and meditation. He borrows heavily from Patanjali and Yagnavalkya but strips away all of the "mysticism" that he sees in them.

I leave it to you to decide if it holds any value as a guide on yoga and meditation, though.

> **Summary on [Goodreads](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/123663.Book_4):**
>
> BOOK FOUR, Parts I and II, together with Magick in Theory and Practice (which is Part III of BOOK FOUR) make up a complete course in Magick, with practical instruction in Yoga and mysticism.
>
> This book is the introduction, the foundation upon which all further magical work will be based. Its simplicity, clarity and depth is without equal in occult literature.
>
> The first part of BOOK FOUR deals with Yoga in a very sound and methodical manner, stripping it of the mysterious and glitter. Soberly, Crowley describes each step as a technique of mental and/or physical discipline, ultimately resulting in complete control of the will and with this, control of the physical and mental body.
>
> Crowley speaks with authority as he is one of the few writers on the subject of Yoga and Magick who has attained Dhyana and Conversation with his Holy Guardian Angel through discipline and ritual practices.
>
> The second part of BOOK FOUR is an encyclopedia of magical symbolism, the working tools in practical magic. All of the paraphernalia employed in ritual magic are carefully explained in both psychological and mystical terms.
>
> The Wand is the will of man, his wisdom, and his word; the Cup is man's understanding, the vehicle of grace; the Sword is reason, the analytical faculty of man; and the Pantacle is man's body, the temple of the Holy Ghost. All phenomena are sacraments. Every fact must enter into the Pantacle. It is the great storehouse from which the Magician draws.
>
> The laws and truths of the occult world which are presented here give the student a sound working knowledge and set him firmly on the path. BOOK FOUR is a concise, direct and honest presentation.

Comment: How is yoga and meditation related to spirituality? I mean do they have philosophical discussion in that book?

Comment: How yoga and meditation are related to spirituality is probably worth a question on its own. Also, philosophical discussions and spirituality are not synonymous, so I'm a bit confused by your comment.

Comment: In spiritual world, yoga means union of atma with parmatma. So it's tightly related. @Knight

Comment: Yoga and SPIRITUALITY are interrelated. You can go through [this answer](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/37008/3869) @Knight

Comment: Yes I will surely look at that.

Answer (score 1):

***A Search In Secret India***: by [Paul Brunton](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paul_Brunton)

The classic work on seeking a guru.

***A Search in Secret India*** is the story of Paul Brunton's journey around India, living among yogis, mystics, and gurus, some of whom he found convincing, others not. He finally finds the peace and tranquility which come with self-knowledge when he meets and studies with the great sage Sri Ramana Maharishi.

---

By [David Frawley](https://www.amazon.in/Books-David-Frawley/s?rh=n%3A976389031%2Cp_27%3ADavid%20Frawley)

He wrote many books on Spiritualism, Hinduism, etc.  Some of them are as follows:

- Gods, Sages and Kings: Vedic Secrets of Ancient Civilization
- Soma in Yoga and Ayurveda: The Power of Rejuvenation and Immortality
- Yoga: A Guide to the Teachings and Practices (Mandala Wisdom)
- Vedic Yoga (the Path of the Rishi)